# Cognito PreSignup Lambda to create user internally first and then in userpool

Tags: authentication, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

We have an existing system where we create the user id (db) internally and use it across db tables as refrential integrity. We are looking to move to Cognito and Api Gateway for authentication and authorization flow. However, we would like to retain the existing identity (user id in db) internally once we authenticate at Api Gateway using Cognito. To do this, we are thinking of using Pre-Signup Lambda trigger to first create the user in our system via that and then Cognito will create the user in the userpool. This way we can associate custom attribute (user id) information using Pre-Token generation lambda which will be passed to Api Gateway with ID Token.

Is this the right approach to create the user first in our system (via Pre-Signup lambda) and then in Cognito?

Comment: It's going to be short, but: Sure, why not? If you need this information already in Cognito then it totally reasonable to create your user first in your own system and only when this was successful - in Cognito.

Comment: Thanks @AleksanderWons. But is this the right approach? I think it is because Signup api supports all necessary params (like client metadata) to pass on data to backend for signup.

Comment: I would say - use whatever feels better for you. If you can easily pass the additional ID through metadata - go that road. But if it's easier to call the user creation API in your system than to already provide it in metadata - go that road. I believe there is no one-size-fits-all here.